# Create association to get related records of same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby 2.1.3 / Rails 3.2.17, I have the following two example classes.

Class `subject`:

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subject_ors # how to specify??
  has_many :alternates  # how to specify??

  # == Schema Information
  #
  # Table name: subjects
  #
  #  id       :integer(4)      not null, primary key
  #  name     :string(255)
end
```

Class `subject_ors`:

```
class SubjectOr < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :left_subject,  foreign_key: :left_id,  class_name: 'Subject'  # don't really need this
  belongs_to :right_subject, foreign_key: :right_id, class_name: 'Subject'  # don't really need this

  # == Schema Information
  #
  # Table name: subject_ors
  #
  #  id       :integer(4)      not null, primary key
  #  left_id  :integer(4)
  #  right_id :integer(4)
end
```

The design intent for `SubjectOr` is that the relations to `Subject` are indifferent and may be referenced as either "left" or "right".  That is, if a given `SubjectOr` is `{ :id => 1, :left_id => 2, :right_id => 3 }` then it would be implied that Subjects[id: 3] would see Subjects[id: 2] as an alternate just as Subjects[id: 2] would see Subjects[id: 3] as an alternate, without needing a symmetrical record in SubjectOrs.

I'd like to create an association in `Subject` called `:alternates` that finds the other `Subjects` for a given `Subject`.  Finding isn't enough or I could just use the following association:

```
has_many  :alternates, class_name: 'Subject', finder_sql: proc { 
  'SELECT DISTINCT subjects.* ' +
    'FROM subjects ' +
  'LEFT JOIN subject_ors AS _left ' +
    'ON _left.left_id = subjects.id ' +
  'LEFT JOIN subject_ors AS _right ' +
    'ON _right.right_id = subjects.id ' +
  "WHERE #{id} IN (_left.right_id, _right.left_id)" 
}
```

This will work to *find* records (really is just a hacked scope), but won't let me do things like `.pluck[:id]` or do ActiveView form operations (such as `accepts_nested_attributes_for`).  A scope won't work for the same reason.

I'm open to do this special association inside of `SubjectOr` instead if I can get the `belongs_to` to see multiple foreign keys for a singular association and then use it for the `has_many` relation in `Subject`. (Seems more appropriate to do in `Subject` but at this point I'm not picky.)

Basically if I could control the underlying query(ies) for the association (beyond just finding records), I think I could make it work.

Some of the things I've tried:

- `finder_sql` -- won't give me all of the features of a full association;
- in `Subject`, multiple targets to `has_many :through` such that 'SubjectOr.left_subject' and 'SubjectOr.right_subject' are simultaneous options for association (doesn't seem possible);
- in `SubjectOr`, multiple foreign keys to a single `belongs_to` association (not allowed);
- special "stabby" conditions, but that doesn't seem to allow self-referential use of the `Subject` record's `:id`.

`SubjectOr` is essentially just a join table on `Subject`, but since I want it to work in both directions off a given SubjectOr` record, and not a parent-child relationship, this is turning out to be surprisingly difficult.

I start getting in over my head doing things like overriding 'load_target' or adding association extensions and such because I'm not sure of the side effects.

Before I go there, does it look like I'm missing something obvious as a way to solve this?

Thanks!
Richard

Comment: Can you preface your question with more about the goal of your code? For example, is your goal something akin to a category tree of subjects such as Science -> Biology -> Medicine ?

Comment: It's simply to allow alternates for a choice.  The example you came up is hierarchical, while I'm trying to just do an arbitrary OR pairing, to be order independent (if A is an alternate to B, then B is one to A).  I'm using to determine prerequisites: given A, B, C, D prereqs, say either B or C could satisfy while A and D must be met by themselves = A + (B or C) + D.  I'm just trying to solve the (B or C) part.

Comment: I'm thinking it's going to be impossible because what I'm trying to accomplish (at least the way I'm going about it) through a `has_many` association means that the foreign keys in `SubjectOr` would be ambiguous to the Rails ORM, through if I could override some association features, I could see making it work.